# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is my code, i'm getting the following error message:
"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0" please help. 
my app is supposed to use the AllWords List
i don't know why its seeing the size as 0 when i added a lot of words' using the SharedPrefrences.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("Words", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        word1 = findViewById(R.id.word1);

        AllWords = GetAllWords();

        word1.setText(AllWords.get(1).toString());
    }

    public List<String> GetAllWords (){
        List<String> AllWords = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
       for(int i=0 ; i<sp.getInt("size",0) ; i++){
            AllWords.add(sp.getString("i",""));
        }
        return AllWords;
    }
```

Comment: can you debug sp and make sure the "size" is not 0?

Comment: I think it's at the command `AllWords.get(1)`. Can you confirm the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` uses `String` keys, not `int`. When you are reading or writing to `SharedPreferences` with string literal `"i"`, you are not indexing the items how you think you are. You are storing a single value and probably over writing it several times.